# How can I have a toc_float in a R bookdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I've been working on a report in `r-markdown` that is getting a bit lengthy and want to break it up into parts with `bookdown`. I'm using a custom html template with a bootstrap menu bar that is enabled in `yaml` front-matter with:

```
toc: true
toc_float: true
```

My reproducible example produces the following error:

> Error in html_document(fig_width = fig_width, fig_height = fig_height,
>   :    You must use a theme when specifying the 'toc_float' option
>   Calls:  ...  -> base_format -> output_format ->
>   html_document

and when I include `theme: default` I get this error:

> Error in html_document(fig_width = fig_width, fig_height = fig_height,
>   :    formal argument "theme" matched by multiple actual arguments
>   Calls:  ... do.call ->  -> base_format ->
>   output_format

The document knits without `toc_float`, but my bootstrap menu bar disappears (as it was designed to do).

Any ideas?

### Parent doc:

````
---
title: "test doc"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    # theme: default
    base_format: rmarkdown::html_vignette
    toc: true
    toc_float: true

---

```{r child = "chapters/01-child.Rmd"}
```
````

### Child doc:

```
#  Child

Child
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly, toc_float does not work with `rmarkdown::html_vignette` as you cannot set a theme.

From the documentation of `rmarkdown::html_vignette`:

> Additional arguments passed to html_document. Please note that theme, fig_retina and highlight are hard coded. Setting any of those will yield an error. [...]
>
> Compared to html_document, it:
>
> - never uses retina figures
> - never uses a theme

However, a possible solution might be to switch from `html_vignette` to `html_document`:

```
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: true
```